# Why RowPersisted is executed twice in Acumatica?

Tags: erp, acumatica

Let's say I've added in my graph some kind of RowPersisted implementation for some DAC. Then I set debugger point on RowPersisted. If to attach in debugging mode, RowPersisted will be executed twice. Why RowPersisted event is executed twice in Acumatica during save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's good to consider, when it is executed. It's really executed twice, the first time during database transaction, and second time after the transaction been commited or aborted. So, it is done for purpose modification of data before commit, and maybe to make some additional actions after it was commited or aborted.